# How is a 2 pass-assembler different from a one pass assembler in resolving the future symbols?

Tags: assembly

These are 2 questions that I don't understand:

1. How does the One-Pass Assembler resolve the future symbol problem?
2. How is Two-Pass Assembler different from the one pass assembler in this respect?

   *Does it resolve it in the first pass or the second pass? If it does it in the second pass,where does it actually differ from the one-pass-assembler? If it does it in the second-pass why doesn't it do in the first pass?*

Answer (score 37):

Read this [PDF](http://solomon.ipv6.club.tw/~solomon/Course/SP/sp2-4.pdf). It explains, step by step, as to how single and multi-pass assemblers work. It also explains the pros and cons of both of them and the differences between the two.

### What is a single pass assembler?

It is a kind of *Load-and-go* type of assembler that generally generates the object code directly in memory for immediate execution! It parses through your source code only once and your done. Vroom...

### Cool, if it does this magic why do we need multi-pass assemblers at all?

Forward references! ie while the one-pass assembler is trodding along your source code, it encounters some ***strangers*** in the form of undefined data symbols and undefined labels(jump addresses). Your assembler asks these strangers as to who are they? The strangers say " *We'll tell you later!*" (Forward reference) Your assembler gets angry and tells you to totally eliminate these strangers. But these strangers are your friends and you cant eliminate them totally. ***So you enter into a compromise deal with the assembler***. You promise to define all your variables before using them. The assembler couldn't compromise on this because it cannot even reserve temp storage for the undefined data symbols as it doesn't know their size. Data can be of varying sizes

If its something like

```
PAVAN EQU SOMETHING

; Your code here
 mov register, PAVAN


; SOMETHING DB(or DW or DD) 80 ; varying size data, not known before
```

On its part your assembler agrees to compromise on undefined jump labels. As jump labels are nothing but addresses and address sizes can be known apriori so that assembler can reserve some definite space for the undefined symbol.

If its like this

```
      jump AHEAD


 AHEAD add reg,#imm
```

Assembler translates `jump AHEAD` as `0x45 **0x00 0x00**`. `0x45` is the opcode of `jump` and 4 bytes reserved for `AHEAD` address

### OK, now tell me how exactly one pass assembler works

***Simple, while on its way, if the assembler encounters an undefined label, it puts it into a symbol table along with the address where the undefined symbol's value has to be placed, when the symbol is found in future***. It does the same for all undefined labels and as and when it sees the definitions of these undefined symbols, it adds their value, both in the table ( thereby making that label defined ) and in the memory location where it had reserved temp storage earlier.

Now at the end of parsing, if there are any more poor souls still in undefined state, the assembler cries foul and errors out :( If there aren't any undefined labels, then off you go!

[image]

### One sec, I forgot why we need a 2 or multi pass assembler? And how do they work?

As explained, **one-pass assembler cannot resolve forward references of data symbols**. It requires all data symbols to be defined prior to being used. A two-pass assembler solves this dilemma by devoting one pass to exclusively resolve all (data/label) forward references and then generate object code with no hassles in the next pass.

If a data symbol depends on another and this another depends on yet another, the assembler resolved this recursively. If I try explaining even that in this post, the post will become too big. Read this [ppt](http://www.csie.nctu.edu.tw/~shieyuan/course/spb/lectures/sp09.ppt) for more details

### Hmm.. Interesting. Does the two pass assembler have any more advantages?

Yes. It can detect redefinitions and things like that.

**PS**: I might not be 100% correct here. I would love to hear any suggestions in making it a better post.

Comment: If one pass assembler cries foul after finding U (when it has scanned the last line),what will 2 pass assembler do in this case ? How is it different from handling U at the end? your answer is not complete and creates many doubts

Comment: I'd say , that it was explained that you can use forward reference with a one pass assembler. There is another thing wrong with this discussion. There is not just one pass, two pass multiple pass assemblers. Most assemblers nowadays generate relocatable, linkable code, which doesn't fit neatly in that scheme.

Comment: -1  One pass assemblers CAN and DO "resolve forward references to data symbols" just fine, or they would be useless.  See my answer. (Resolved this "recursively"? No need).

Comment: @AlbertvanderHorst: Handling relocatable symbols is not hard with a one pass assembler.  The linker has to help, but it has to do that anyway even for a two pass assembler with relocatable symbols.

Comment: Sire you deserve a cookie for such a great answer

Answer (score 14):

A one pass assembler generates code and for any undefined symbols, leaves a slot to be filled in, and remembers it in a table or other data structure. Then where the symbol is defined, it fills in its value at the right place or places, using the information from the table.

The reason for using a two pass assembler traditionally has been that the target program doesn't fit in memory, leave alone the source. The gigantic source program is read, line by line, from the punch tape reader, and the table of labels is kept in internal memory.
(I've actually done that, on ISIS, the first development system of Intel, with an 8080.)
The second time around the source tape is again read from the beginning, but the value of all labels is known, and as each line is read, the target program is punched out to tape. On a memory starved 16 bit Intel 8086 system this was still a useful technique to have a heavily documented source file that can be much larger than 64 Kbyte, with hard disk or floppy substituted for paper tape.

Nowadays there is no need to do two passes, but this architecture is still in use. It is slightly simpler, at the expense of I/O.

Comment: I often argue that going back through the tables is a second or third or fourth pass.  Not across the source it self but across the data that represents the source.  Two pass as you have described it  still puts you in a bind if the label table is too big for memory as well, granted that takes a lot longer than trying to keep the table and the output binary in memory at the same time.  My definition of two pass is wrong from the historical sense that it does not need to make a pass on the source again. it makes two passes, but not on the source.

Comment: Nice concise answer, I like it...I see your low score, please spend more time at SO providing more excellent answers. (its not about the score IMO, it is about sharing the wealth of knowledge)

Comment: dwelch: "still puts you in a bind .." With all due respects, but the dynamics of programming has changed a bit. I'm typing this on an 8 Gbyte RAM machine. The idea that it couldn't hold a table of names in RAM presupposes a really ludicrously large program, never been written, never will be written.

Comment: One could have a practical assembler system using even something as primitive as a paper tape reader and punch, processing each tape once, with memory only large enough to hold a list of symbols and pending fixups, but not the whole file, if the code loader can handle records in arbitrary order. The executable tape would be longer than ideal, but assembling a file on a system with no storage other than a paper tape would be practical: feed the tape containing the assembler, then the source text, and get a tape containing the executable.  Reset the system and load the executable.

Comment: mr supercat: Your example is far from imaginary. Philips first in circuit emulator for microcomputers, run on a Z80 and had to be assembled on an Intel Isis development system. It took hours and proceeded just like you described. One of my first jobs.

Answer (score 9):

One way to think about assemblers is to imagine that they compute the value of a series of expressions assigned to sequentially increasing memory locations.   The expressions may conventionally consist of the value of a symbol, some arithmetic done on symbols, constants, and special variables such as the "current location counter" (often written with a funny name such as "$"), or truly peculiar expressions whose syntax is that of machine instructions.

Note that an expression may produce a value that fills several sequential memory locations; machine instructions tend to do this, but it is useful to have expressions for string literals, multiprecision numbers, initialized structs, etc.   This only affects bookkeeping details but doesn't change what assemblers do in the abstract.

To compute the final value of each expression, the assembler must know the value of any symbols that might be involved.   It discovers symbol values in only a few ways.   First, the symbol value might be defined as the result of an expression.  Second, the symbol value might be assigned the value of the current location counter; typically assemblers do this when a symbol is written in "label" position.  On such discovery, the assembler records the symbol name and its value in the symbol table to use in evaluating expressions.

A key problem an assembler faces is producing the value of an expression, having not yet encountered all the definitions of symbols.  The assumption is that if a symbol is not defined in some particular line, it will be defined in some later line that the assembler will eventually process.

A two pass assembler tries to compute the value of each expression as it encounters it, in two passes called "first" and "second" passes.   During first pass, if there are undefined symbols (presumed to be forward references) in the expression, the assembler simply substitutes a dummy value (often zero); in any case, it computes a value for the expression.  If a machine instruction or data constant is being processed, the results are ignored, but the *size* is used to advance the location counter to enable label value assignment.  If a label is encountered, its value is set to the current location counter.  If a symbol assignment "A EQU " is encountered, the symbol value is set to the result of the expression; if the expression contained an undefined symbol, the assembler will emit an error.   If an origin statement is found "ORG ", it is treated as if one wrote "$ EQU ".  At the end of the first pass, all labels have been assigned values; any symbols that do not have values are marked as "undefined" in the symbol table.   A second pass repeats the expression evaluation of the first but does not (re)define any symbols; since all symbols are (expected to be) defined, the expression values are correct and emitted to the output stream.  Any undefined symbols found in an expression cause an "undefined symbol" complaint.

A one-pass assembler tries to compute the value of each expression as it encounters the expression.  If the expression contains only defined symbols, the assembler can evaluate it and produce the final value, and write that information to its output stream.   (Another answer here suggested that some one pass assemblers write their answer to memory.  That's just a special case).  If the expression contains an undefined symbol, the assembler stores a pair *(location,expression)* to be reprocessed later, either when the symbol becomes defined, or at end of assembly.  Some expressions such as those that set the location counter can't have undefined symbols; the assembler will complain in that case.

So the tricky part is storing the unresolved expression, and deciding when to re-evaluate it.   One way to store the expression is to simply keep the text; another is to build what amounts to a (reverse) Polish notation for the expression.  To determine when the expression needs to be re-evaluated, one can associate it with the undefined symbols it contains; then when a symbol gets defined, the corresponding unresolved expressions are re-evaluated, with completed ones being emitted, and unresolved ones left again for reprocessing.    Alternatively the assembler could simply save all the expressions until it encounters the end of input; at this point, all symbols should be defined and so it should be able to determine final values for each expression.  One chooses between these two techniques based on how much memory one can afford to store forward reference expressions.

In a previous century, I built a one-pass assembler that ran on an 8k byte computer, that used the Polish representation of expressions.  As symbols were defined, the Polish expression was evaluated and any subexpressions that were computable were computed, simplifying the resulting Polish either to a final value or a smaller Polish expression involving only the operators on undefined symbols.  Symbol table entries for undefined values had a linked list of all the Polish expression slots corresponding to undefined symbols; as symbol definitions were encountered, all elements of the linked-list were updated and Polish expressions were re-evaluated as that occurred.  This keeps the Polish expression sizes as small as possible and gets rid of them the moment all of their symbols are defined.   This assembler processed hundred thousand line programs just fine in small machine.  The reason for doing a one pass assembler in such a small machine is the source code came from paper tape (a Teletype, for those of you old enough to remember) and reading that paper tape even once is pretty painful and slow; a second time was not a good idea, so a two pass assembler was not an appropriate choice.

One of my cohorts much later built an interesting two pass assembler.  Rather than processing the *text* twice, he tokenized the text (storing it in memory) on the first pass as well as collecting symbol values.   Pass two processed the tokenized text.
This was a very fast assembler for two passes.   He had a lot more memory available.

Comment: On some systems, making more than two passes may be helpful.  The first pass won't know how large branch instructions need to be, but will be able to compute approximate addresses.  The second pass can use the approximate addresses to establish which branches should be short or long, but won't know the exact target addresses.  The third pass will be able to plug in actual target addresses if every branch instruction is made the same length as in the second pass.

Comment: There are many assemblers that iterate on converting long to short instructions.  MASM is one of them.   Yes, you have to do that after you have a good idea of the sizes of the instructions between the branches.  If you have a one-pass assembler, you can do this for backward branches pretty well in the first pass.  If you have an N pass assembler, you do this kind of optimization in pass N+1, agreed.  Sometimes you only have to iterate once to get very good results and you can just agree to quit there.

Comment: The simplest approach is to keep track of whether any symbols changed, and iterate until none do; if one allows ".set" labels as well as ".equ" labels, one can include a new symbol table entry every time a ".set" label changes, and check whether the Nth rewrite of a set label on a given pass matches the Nth rewrite on the previous pass.

Comment: This is the classic paper on how to do this efficiently, including chaining short branches that happen to reach the right place:  http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.90.3786&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: Branch chaining can sometimes improve run-time efficiency, but it can sometimes make it less predictable.  Depending upon what code is doing, that may or may not be acceptable.

Answer (score -2):

Future Symbol Probleam Means The Symbol Is Use Before It Is Define.

- It Is Possible Because In Assembly Language Program, Programmer Can Define Symbol Anywere So If Symbol Is Use Before It's Define It's Called "forward reference"
- So At A Time From Converting It Into Machine(Binary) Language ,Assembler get Opcode-Reg-X2-B2 But It Diden't Get D2(Displacement) entry in Symbol Table, So It Is Not Possible To Convert Into Machine Language(Binary) And It's Called "Forward Reference Problem".
- To Solving This 2 Pass Assembler Is Define.

**At First Pass(First Scan) It Make Entries Of Symbols(Labels) Into The Symbol Table.
**And At Second Pass(Second Time Scan) Assembler Convert It Into Machine Language(Binary). It's Very Simple :)

Comment: The weird capitalization really detracts from the usefulness of the answer. Why do that?